# SAML JIT Handler - how to link Contact to User

Tags: single-sign-on, jit-handler, jit

I have this single sign on configuration:

- **SAML Identity Type**: Assertion contains the Federation ID from the User object
- **SAML Identity Location**: Identity is in the NameIdentifier element of the Subject statement
- **Service Provider Initiated Request Binding**: HTTP POST
- **Just-in-time User Provisioning**: **Enabled** with **Custom SAML JIT with Apex handler**

I'm using a implementation based on this one: https://gist.github.com/johndstein/93d81bcc7ae746e277eaa1d91364c4b8

I'm creating the account + contact and assigned it to the user

```
global User createUser(Id samlSsoProviderId, Id communityId, Id portalId,
                       String federationIdentifier, Map<String, String> attributes, String assertion) {

    User user = new User();
    Contact contact = new Contact();
    /** ... parse saml ** */
    insert contact;
    user.ContactId = contact.Id;
    System.debug(user.ContactId);  // this prints the contact id 003
    return user;
}
```

I assume the JIT framework is making dml to insert the user, but, when the insert is done the user been inserted does not have the ContactId populated

I created a trigger on user to print the value and it is null

```
trigger User_trg on User (before insert) {
    System.debug(Trigger.new[0].ContactId); // this prints null
}
```

Checking the logs (with all the debug levels set to finest):

```
..............................
13:59:28.818 (8864843012)|USER_DEBUG|[241]|WARN|contactid in jit handler 0031q00000rLjTrAAK
13:59:28.818 (8864857776)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[241]|System.debug(APEX_OBJECT, ANY)
13:59:28.818 (8865492245)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
13:59:28.818 (8865655656)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:8
13:59:28.818 (8865679889)|DML_BEGIN|[EXTERNAL]|Op:Insert|Type:User|Rows:1
13:59:28.818 (8865757085)|LIMIT_USAGE|[EXTERNAL]|DML|2|150
13:59:28.818 (8865774430)|LIMIT_USAGE|[EXTERNAL]|DML_ROWS|2|10000
13:59:28.818 (8865798396)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:8
13:59:28.818 (8904714617)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Flow:User
13:59:28.818 (8904750959)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Flow:User
13:59:28.818 (8912176842)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q0X000000VnDG|User_trg on User trigger event BeforeInsert|__sfdc_trigger/User_trg
13:59:28.818 (8912249894)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:8
13:59:28.818 (8912420107)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:31
13:59:28.818 (8912447917)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:4
13:59:28.818 (8912463271)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[8]|this|User_trg|true|false
13:59:28.818 (8912662183)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[8]|this|{}|0x66d1ec5f
13:59:28.818 (8912738442)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:4
13:59:28.818 (8912752510)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[8]|this|User_trg|true|false
13:59:28.818 (8912858015)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[8]|this|{}|0x66d1ec5f
13:59:28.818 (8912876040)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[8]
13:59:28.818 (8912887989)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[9]
13:59:28.818 (8912895925)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[9]|Bytes:10
13:59:28.818 (8912983067)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[9]|Bytes:4
13:59:28.818 (8913103823)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[9]|String.valueOf(Object)
13:59:28.818 (8913149121)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[9]|String.valueOf(Object)
13:59:28.818 (8913167003)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[9]|Bytes:14
13:59:28.818 (8913189715)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[9]|System.debug(ANY)
13:59:28.818 (8913202780)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|contactid in user trigger null
..............................
```

I have a possible workaround and it is to get the contact id in the trigger. I was able to do it this way, but I would love to know how to do this Out of the Box without this tricks

Any idea what could be happening?

Comment: insert your User in the handler, it'll work. From [createUser doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_interface_Auth_SamlJitHandler.htm#apex_Auth_SamlJitHandler_createUser): _This object can be a new user that hasn’t been inserted in the database or an existing user record in the database_

Comment: and that did the tick @identigral thanks!